# Can I find out when was a specific edit added to a tag-wiki or post?

Tags: feature-request, edits, tag-wiki, revision-history

[javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) has a great big description that has [10 pages of edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3607052/revisions) (and counting).

Between [the first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3607052/1) and [the current one (226<sup>th</sup>)](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3607052/226) someone added this:

> Debug your JavaScript code (see Creativebloq, MDN, Google, & MSDN).

Any JavaScript developer knows about MDN, Google, or MSDN but, even if I have several years of JavaScript experience, I've never heard of Creativebloq (especially as a first option in such a list), so it seems to me as someone added it there to promote their site.

To find out which revision added it, I would have to go through 226 revisions and see what was the reason (in case I am mistaken and Creativeblog is indeed an official source).

Could I instead search for "Creativebloq" in the revision history and see which revision added it?

I find this feature to be useful for posts as well, so any post with revision history.

Comment: Instead of a linear search for the revision, try a binary search / bisection. [#108](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3607052/108) is the first revision to add `Creativebloq`.

Answer (score 2):

You can search revisions using [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com). Since it's a niche feature, that's likely sufficient.

I've created a sample tag wiki search query [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/946327/search-tag-wiki-history-example?TagName=javascript).

You can add `AND ph.Text LIKE '%creativebloq%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI` to do a case-insensitive search for creativebloq.

That leads to [revision 108](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3607052/108), like already identified by Sebastian Simon.

This, unfortunately, requires a bit of T-SQL knowledge.

Comment: Re *"... requires a bit of T-SQL knowledge"*: There is [a SEDE tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial/intro-to-databases): ***"But First: A Very Brief Introduction to Databases"***. This could be added to your answer.